# What does “you you’re writing about” means in the following content?

Tags: meaning

> Yes. I wrote from the point of view of someone who was sad. But when
>   you’re taking on a part, it’s usually you you’re writing about. Your
>   psychiatrist would say it’s you.

Comment: Pleas wait at least couple of days before accepting an answer. You may get an even better one. People may not want to write you an answer if they see that you have already selected one.

Comment: @Araucaria - It is possible to change your acceptance. When a better answer comes along, you simply tick that and the acceptance moves.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes, but generally people don't like to answer questions that already have accepted answers. Many people don't bother to read them either. It's bad for the site in general when answers are accepted too quickly.

Comment: @Araucaria - I don't agree with your premise. I often look at accepted answers. Sometimes I doubt their accuracy and comment. Do you have any quantitative evidence that *'people don't like to answer questions that already have accepted answers'* ?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It's a fact well bandied around by mods. If you want their evidence why don't you ask a question on meta about it.

Comment: @Araucaria - Okay. Let's not argue about it. When someone makes a claim it is for *them* to provide the evidence, not the person questioning the claim. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26926/discussion-between-chasly-from-uk-and-araucaria).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when you’re taking on a part, it’s usually you you’re writing about. Your psychiatrist would say it’s you.

Paraphrase

*But when you’re taking on a part, it’s usually you[rself that] you’re writing about. Your psychiatrist would say it’s you.*

"You" is the object of    "are writing about"